# Does anyone know of a Primer for reading an Access database from VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

In the near future I'll need to start reading an Access 2003 database from a VB6 application. Does anyone know of a 'get you started' guide to the mechanics of doing this (how to get a connection, how to send a query, that sort of thing).

Comment: You must first decide wether you're going to use DAO or ADO. Once you know that, you can nearly copy paste any similar VBA code.

Comment: There is no database access code currently lying around for Mr Cut and Mr Paste to get to work on. Strange but true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-jet-data-access-objects

Comment: Thank you for the help: that's got me started.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with this:

[image: You're gonna need it]

Otherwise, I'd suggest any title that starts you off with basics but has a reasonable coverage of more intermediate to advanced topics would suffice.  For example, [this title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0046LUOEQ).

Ultimately though, I think your best resource will be the web and Stack Overflow in particular.

Comment: It's long since too late for that book to be much use, I'm afraid.